# Invalid CSRF token using flag.link_builder service (Flag module)

Tags: 8, flags, csrf

I have a REST route that returns a list of user accounts. I have a flag setup called 'following' as you can follow and unfollow other members. In my REST route, I use:

`$flag_link = \Drupal::service('flag.link_builder')->build('user', $member->id(), 'following');`

which generates the link correctly as far as I can tell. In my javascript object I can see the link that was created. This is an example of the JS object of a user that I use on the front end:

```
0:
  flag_link:
    #access: true
    #action: "flag"
    #attached: {placeholders: {…}, library: Array(1)}
    #attributes: {title: "", href: "/flag/unflag/following/3?destination&token=LEfyLe9PPaQfgNNRSXUA82k4SVHQGRmBEI0adgBva9g", class: Array(1)}
    #cache: {contexts: Array(1), tags: Array(0), max-age: -1}
    #flag: {id: "following", label: "Following"}
    #flaggable: {}
    #theme: "flag"
    #title: {#markup: "Follow this person"}
  id: "3"
  name: "ronnie"
  url: "/user/3"
```

When I go to click the link it 403 forbiddens with the message `message: "'csrf_token' URL query argument is invalid."`

The HTML I am outputting is:

```
<div class="flag">
  <a href="/flag/unflag/following/3?destination&token=LEfyLe9PPaQfgNNRSXUA82k4SVHQGRmBEI0adgBva9g" class="use-ajax" rel="nofollow">Unfollow this person</a>
</div>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Here is a screen shot of my request when I click the anchor
[image]

Comment: What is the connection between the service and your JS? I'm confused on that from your post. I can't really follow how these are connected. What I can say is that you are getting an 403 error because that route expects a CSRF token, which it is not receiving.

Comment: The service returns a JSON object. That JSON object contains some info about users. The service is also returning a Flag link using the link_builder service that ships with the flag module. That is the JS object in that block of code above. I am outputting that flag link in a block. The link looks just like any other flag field that would be output using the entity display page. I was under the impression the token being passed IS the CSRF token. Hopefully that answers your question

Comment: I have only briefly looked at REST as I did not need it, but from the documentation you should be sending that token in a Headers. See section 2.2 : https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest/1-getting-started-rest-configuration-rest-request-fundamentals

Comment: You are passing `token`. The callback says it is expecting `csrf_token`. But maybe Neograph's comment is more suited to your problem

Comment: yeah, I am not sure. My request is identical to a flag link when output using a display mode. A regular flag link request does not include the X-CSRF-Token header. In my searches there is another error message similar to this one, but says its missing. Mine is saying its invalid

Comment: Are you currently logged in with the same User as `$member->id()` the link was generated for?

Comment: No. For example, I am logged in as admin (user 1) viewing a list of members. Under each member has a follow/unfollow link generated by the code in my OP. `$member->id()` would be referring to other members, not myself if thats what you meant

Comment: you need to add into the POST method of the csrf token, as I can see its permissions denied, and also please check your user permissions, are you allowed to create or flag?

Comment: Similar question [Fix for “'csrf_token' URL query argument is invalid” error during logout](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/294070/fix-for-csrf-token-url-query-argument-is-invalid-error-during-logout)

Comment: @Boby yes I have permissions. I dont need to add the X-CSRF-Token request header. The token is in the url parameters. This error is originating from Drupal\Core\Access\CsrcAccessCheck.php https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Access%21CsrfAccessCheck.php/8.8.x. The token is not missing, it fails on the validation check

Answer (score 0):

I created an example. You can check it and find the solution there.

https://github.com/Mykola-Veryha/ajax-flag-link

Comment: care to expand?