# Fix for "'csrf_token' URL query argument is invalid" error during logout

Tags: 8, csrf

I am creating a set of API endpoints for a mobile app using Rest. For User authentication, I am using the default API endpoints supplied by Drupal. That would be

```
/user/logout?_format=json&token=<logout_token obtained from login api response.>
```

I wanted to remove the _format=json from the URL parameter and so I created a custom route with the existing controller just for this purpose. However, I am getting an error.

```
"'csrf_token' URL query argument is invalid
```

I am not able to figure out how to remove this error. I had added a csrf_token as an additional parameter with the one I got from successful login. It seems however that the csrf token being validated against is generated somewhere else.

I can remove this error by removing the csrf token entry from the routing file entry but that would be a security violation. How do we fix this error or is there a better way to handle the user logout api endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the right **csrf_token** you should first request `/session/token` this route coming from [system.routing.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21system.routing.yml/8.9.x) so in your controller action add those two things:

1. Get the system **csrf_token** from `/session/token`
2. Add your csrf token to header request as `X-CSRF-Token`

**Update**:
If you are using rest module you should get the csrf token from `/rest/session/token` instead of `/session/token`

Comment: Hi. I've tried this solution but It doesn't work for me. I always get the error. I've tried with csrf-token got on login and with the one requested with session/token, but none of them work. Always the same error.

Comment: Ive also tried this and getting same error whether i use login reply token or session token. calling it /session/token is also bad labelling if its a csrf token.

Comment: There's no `rest/session/token`, at least not in Drupal 10 now. `session/token` gives the same error, as well as using the original token from your login.

Answer (score 2):

You can use POST method on */user/logout* without params and token, the cookie will be deleted so the user will be logged out, but in the server-side Drupal will not destroy the session, so you'll end up by having a lot of unused sessions...

I wonder why do you want to remove the *_format=json* from the URL ?

Comment: I wanted to provide a cleaner url.  The _format=json is not required in our case as it is a partially decoupled system. The parameter is only to differentiate between HTML and JSON logins which is useful for stock Drupal site but looks bad in our case.  I am using post method but I am always getting csrf error.